# AlarmManager's setRepeating() does not repeat, setInexactRepeating() does not work at all

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, repeat

this is my activiy_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Example"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Schedule" 
    android:onClick="scheduleAlarm"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity
  {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

public void scheduleAlarm(View V)
{
        Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+10*1000;
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(1, time, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled for 10 Seconds",                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
  }
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
      public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
      {
     @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }

      }
```

I also have these added to my Manifest file:

```
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"/> 
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

This is my whole example application. When I click the `Button` it does what I want it to do after 10 seconds, display a `Toast` saying "Alarm Triggered". But does it only once with `setRepeating()` method. What I want is that it repeats forever, I will use this code for polling but I don't get why it does not repeat. Should I also use `setInexactRepeating()` for polling? that one doesn't work at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This was only my foolishness, I am going to keep this question in case anyone else falls for the same thing.

```
  alarmManager.setRepeating(type, triggerAtMillis, intervalMillis, operation);
```

you cannot set the `intervalMillis` like below

```
  new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+10*1000;
```

you need to set it a value like `10*1000`